# Any Full "Ruby Stack" AMI on EC2?

Tags: ruby, web-services, amazon-ec2, nginx, cloud

What is best available EC2 AMI that have satisfy following must have?

- Ruby Stack Pre Installed
- MySql Installed and configured with Ruby
- Monit Installed
- Nginx
- Secure SSH access

Please let me know AMI you are recommending you have used or not?

Amazon lacks proper review system for AMI unlike product/book previews.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to [BitNami RubyStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack) which you can install in your system, download a virtual machine or deploy on Amazon EC2 or GoGrid cloud. You have the exact environment, gem versions, database version, etc on your system and on the cloud so there is no surprise when you move your app to the cloud. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to afford them, I would recommend [EngineYard's Cloud](http://www.engineyard.com/products/cloud), which is built with EC2 AMIs.  They are around 30% more expensive than EC2 on-demand rates last time I checked.

[ec2onrails](http://ec2onrails.rubyforge.org/) is a good start, but the project has stagnated, and I don't believe there is a release version that uses EBS for the database files, although the development branches do have that feature.  I have used it and it worked well.  You will definitely want your database on EBS for snapshot and mobility reasons.

There are a few others floating around but I have not looked at them.

I ended up rolling my own using Passenger, which was not very difficult and left me far more comfortable.  Your requirements are pretty basic.

Comment: Alex, thanks for answer. I'm rolling my own since two years and keeping those installation as AMI but normally when it comes time again using AMI many things have changed. And now I feel that bit outdated and again rolled my own. Just wanted to get out of that cycle with some pre built up-to-date AMIs, exactly something like EY Cloud. Which I think over priced.